# Visual Studio 2017: Event-call when user changes tab

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, rendering, extending, outliner

I'm trying to write an outliner for XML code in VS (an extension using their SDK from a VSIX template) and I would like to get an event-call whenever the user changes to a different codeview/document.

Then, I plan to check the document type, create and render an interactive outline if it is indeed an xml document.

How would I go about creating such a hooking and is it even necessary?

**EDIT**

I've attempted the following implementation, but I'm being told that object does not contain a definition for "GetGlobalService"

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

[Guid("bc4c5e8f-a492-4a44-9e57-ec9ad945140e")]
public class OutlineWindow : ToolWindowPane
{

    private DTE dte;

    public OutlineWindow() : base(null)
    {
        this.Caption = "OutlineWindow";

        this.Content = new OutlineWindowControl();

        dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE.DTE;
        dte.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += OnWindowActivated;
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(Window gotFocus, Window lostFocus)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The VS internal structure changes a lot do this may not still be valid, but see [Event when a Document Window is focus in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001240/event-when-a-document-window-is-focus-in-visual-studio)

Comment: That looks like it could have worked, but I'm being told that 
'object' does not contain a definition for 'Package.GetGlobalService' etc.

Which is what I've run into with numerous of the ways I've attempted to do it earlier.

Comment: Maybe you're missing a cast. Can you edit your question with the relevant code?

Comment: I just created a new empty class with the same code (I literally copy-pasted it from the class that was complaining), and it comes up with no errors, and from that I discovered that the problem was the inheritance from ToolWindowPane .. doh
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @stuartd I managed to get this working!
My problem was actually that I was putting it in the wrong class, the inheritance was messing it up.

```
public class OutlineManager
{
    private DTE dte;

    public OutlineManager()
    {
        dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
        dte.Events.WindowEvents.WindowActivated += OnWindowActivated;
    }

    private void OnWindowActivated(Window gotFocus, Window lostFocus)
    {
        //This is run when a new "window"(panel) gains focus (not only the code window though)
    }
}
```